# Correct hibernate criteria for this model

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have the following model:

```
class TeamEntity {

  private List<UserEntity> users = new ArrayList<UserEntity>();

  private List<TeamAdminPermissionEntity> permissions = new ArrayList<TeamAdminPermissionEntity>();

  ...

}

class UserEntity {

  private List<TeamEntity> teams = new ArrayList<TeamEntity>();

  private List<TeamAdminPermissionEntity> permissions = new ArrayList<TeamAdminPermissionEntity>();

  ...

}

class TeamAdminPermissionEntity() {

  private UserEntity ownerUser;
  private TeamEntity ownerTeam;

  ...

}
```

So, a TeamEntity can have many permissions associated with it, where each permission has an owner team and an owner user. A UserEntity can also have many permissions. A TeamEntity can have many UserEntities, and UserEntities can be part of many TeamEntities.

So, given I have a:

- id of one particular team

What I need is:

- a list of UserEntities within that particular TeamEntity who do *not* already have aTeamAdminPermission for that team

Ideally I'd like to use the CriteriaBuilder, but HQL/SQL is good too.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`List<UserEntity> results = (List<UserEntity>) session.createCriteria(UserEntity.class).add(Restrictions.eq(TeamAdminPermission, false)`